# calculate all possible combinations of RNA codons for a protein sequence

Tags: python, tuples, bioinformatics

i have a protein sequence:

```
sequence_protein = 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL'
```

and a tRNA codon table for every protein:

```
codon_table = {
'A': ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
'C': ('TGT', 'TGC'),
'D': ('GAT', 'GAC'),
'E': ('GAA', 'GAG'),
'F': ('TTT', 'TTC'),
'G': ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
'H': ('CAT', 'CAC'),
'I': ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
'K': ('AAA', 'AAG'),
'L': ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
'M': ('ATG',),
'N': ('AAT', 'AAC'),
'P': ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
'Q': ('CAA', 'CAG'),
'R': ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
'S': ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG', 'AGT', 'AGC'),
'T': ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
'V': ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
'W': ('TGG',),
'Y': ('TAT', 'TAC'),}
```

i then wrote a function that would give a tuple with the possible codons for every protein:

```
tRNA = []
for i in sequence_protein:
    for residue in i:
        tRNA.append(codon_table[residue])
```

which gave this output:

```
[('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
 ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
 ('CAT', 'CAC'),
 ('ATG',),
 ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
 ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
 ('TGT', 'TGC'),
 ('TAT', 'TAC'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
 ('CAT', 'CAC'),
 ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
 ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
 ('TGG',),
 ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('GAT', 'GAC'),
 ('TAT', 'TAC'),
 ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
 ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('AAT', 'AAC'),
 ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
 ('ATG',),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('TGT', 'TGC'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG')]
```

is there a way to compute all possible codon combinations for the sequence (basically calculate the products for all the seperate elements in the tuple)?
and also count the amount of products there would be without generating the sequences first?

i tried using the product function but that crashed my notebook :s

```
combs = []
for a in product(*tRNA):
    combs.append(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: Is this exercise part of your homeworks?

Comment: That crashed because it just too big, don't store all at once. If you want to computation on it, do it in the loop

Comment: As @azro says, there are too many of them. In fact, there are 37,572,373,905,408 (37.5 trillion) such sequences. Unless you have access to a supercomputer, this isn't going to be feasible for you, even if you leave the product as a generator.

Comment: @JohnColeman Can you please elaborate on the process of computing that number? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### To calculate the total number of combinations:

```
sequence_protein = 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL'
total_number_combinations = np.prod([ len(codon_table[aa]) for aa in sequence_protein ])
```

#### To generate all possible combinations:

The most elegant is itertools:

```
from itertools import product

tRNA = [codon_table[aa] for aa in sequence_protein]
for i in product(*tRNA):
    #...do whatever you have to do with these combinations.
```

but you can use a custom function. Just use `yield` so that you don't generate all sequences at once and avoid memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

list_codons = [('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
 ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
 ('CAT', 'CAC'),
 ('ATG',),
 ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
 ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
 ('TGT', 'TGC'),
 ('TAT', 'TAC'),
 ('GAA', 'GAG'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
 ('CAT', 'CAC'),
 ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'),
 ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
 ('TGG',),
 ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('GAT', 'GAC'),
 ('TAT', 'TAC'),
 ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
 ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'),
 ('AAT', 'AAC'),
 ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'),
 ('ATG',),
 ('CAA', 'CAG'),
 ('TGT', 'TGC'),
 ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG')]

counter = 0; max_proc = 1000000; list_seq = []

for x in itertools.product(*list_codons):
    counter += 1
    if counter % max_proc == 0:
        #Do your stuff by slice and clear the list
        list_seq = []
    list_seq.append(x)
    print (counter)
    print (x)
```

And that's it, no more RAM problem

Comment: There is no RAM problem -- but it is doubtful that looping over all such things will be feasible.

Comment: There is RAM problem. I can tell you I crashed my own laptop using simply output = list(itertools.product(*list_codons))

Comment: @azro there is, see edit. If you can't manage that much of combinations at once, you "slice" by a max proc var, you store whatever wherever, and you combine later

Comment: My point was that, yes, there is no RAM problem in your code, but attempting to loop over the whole product is still infeasible.

Comment: well, your point was right. But pratically talking, as the OP mentioned, there was a RAM problem due to the code in the context of the task/resource. That's why slicing is certainly the way to manage it.

Comment: thank you, i modified your code a bit and now have: `from itertools import product

counter = 0; max_proc = 5000; list_seq = []

for x in product(*tRNA):
    counter += 1
    if counter % max_proc == 0:
        print(f'possible amount of sequences exceed 5000')
        break` to simply stop counting after the amount of combinations exceeds 5000

Comment: Well, if you don't mind about processing the whole dataset and the first 5000 are ok, then it is good! If that is fine now, you can think about accepting the answer ;)